# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'year'

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, object

[This is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULK42.jpg)
I'm supposed to create 3 instances of the class movie with 3 different movies but I keep on encountering Attribute Error. I have no clue on how to solve. I'm new to the concept of OOPS.

```
class Movie:
    # create class here
    def __init__(self, title, director, year):
        self.title = title
        self.director = director
        self.year = year
# objects of the class Movie
titanic = Movie("Titanic", "James Cameron", "1997")
star_wars = Movie("Star Wars", "George Lucas", "1977"),
fight_club = Movie("Fight Club", "David Fincher", "1999")
```

Comment: Can you share the actual code that causes the error and the stack trace as the code you pasted doesnt produce any error.

Comment: This is the actual code that produced the error. I copied and pasted it from the window directly. Will a screenshot be useful?

Comment: I have run your code and it doesnt give any error. there must be more code than this, there must be something in your code that at some point you are trying to access year but have perhaps accidentlly allocated a tuple to the variable. Right now the error cannot be reproduced and looking at your current code you posted i dont see how it could ever give the attribute error in the title.

Comment: Does this issue occur when you try to access year of one of the objects?

Comment: I've edited the question with image for your reference.

Comment: oh wait, your issue is the comma on the starwars line, your making pythong think this is a tuple. Just remove the trailing comma on the starwars line

Comment: Oh thank you so much Chris. I'm such a dweeb. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the trailing comma on the second last line as python is considering this as a one item tuple which contains a movie.

change

`star_wars = Movie("Star Wars", "George Lucas", "1977"),`

to

`star_wars = Movie("Star Wars", "George Lucas", "1977")`

you can see what was happening by looking at the object.

```py
print(type(star_wars))
print(type(star_wars[0]))
print(star_wars[0].year)
```

```
<class 'tuple'>
<class '__main__.Movie'>
1977
```